# Batch File to Copy Files

Tags: vbscript

I have a list of 150 computers on my Windows Active Directory network that I am trying to copy a files to.
I wonder if someone might have a script that would, copy the files or shortcut to the computers by looking for the PC names in a text file.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do this with a group policy?

Comment: This would be pretty easy to do with PowerShell and not that complex. Are you not familiar with desktop/management scripting?

Answer (score 5):

The right™ way to do this is to use a startup/logon script in GPO
*or*
Use a Group Policy [File](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771102.aspx)/[Shortcut](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753580.aspx) Preference item if your clients are Vista/7 or XP w/ the GPP Extensions add-on.

The reason that you don't want to do this the way that you proposed is that if a computer is not on or is unavailable or has a file locked, this won't work. A logon script or GPO gets around this restriction and guarantees that computers in your organization are compliant.

---

If you really want to use a script for this and feed it names, I recommend PowerShell. You can use `Get-Content` to read the list and pipe it to a `ForEach-Object` that will then contain a `Copy-Item` command with a destination of `\\$_\C$\Path\To\Copy\To`.

If you want more info on any of these cmdlets, just run `Get-Help *command* -full`. For example, if you wanted the full details w/ examples of how `Copy-Item` works, just run `Get-Help Copy-Item -full`.

Comment: `s/logon/computer\ startup/`, depending upon where the file needs to be placed of course.

Comment: @Bryan I don't know *what* you're talking about ;-)

Comment: i really dont want to user GPO to get this done i pretty do all my deployment using KACE. i already have a batch file to get this done i used to write VBS script. just checking if anyone already have a script they would be willing to share but thanks for the information guys

Comment: So, if you already use KACE for config management why aren't you using KACE for this? Also, GPO and config management tools like KACE are complimentary technology. Many large scale deployments leverage *both* technologies to keep their environment in good shape.

Comment: i am using kace to deploy a the batch files